# this.canvasElement.getContext is not a function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my document I'm referring jQuery version 3.1.0, as well as oCanvas version 2.8.1. This is how I have my scripts represented in my document:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ocanvas/2.8.1/ocanvas.min.js"></script>
```

My code creates fading circles within the `canvas` element as such:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {


    var windowXArray = [],
        windowYArray = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < $(window).innerWidth(); i++) {
        windowXArray.push(i);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < $(window).innerHeight(); i++) {
        windowYArray.push(i);
    }

    function randomPlacement(array) {
        var placement = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
        return placement;
    }

    var canvas = oCanvas.create({
      canvas: '#connect',
      //background: '#131417',
      fps: 60
    });

    setInterval(function() {

        var rectangle = canvas.display.ellipse({
            x: randomPlacement(windowXArray),
            y: randomPlacement(windowYArray),
            origin: {
                x: 'center',
                y: 'center'
            },
            radius: 0,
            fill: '#fff',
            opacity: 1
        });

        canvas.addChild(rectangle);

        rectangle.animate({
            radius: 10,
            opacity: 0
        }, {
            duration: '1000',
            easing: 'linear',
            callback: function() {
                this.remove();
            }
        });

    }, 100);

    $(window).resize(function() {
        canvas.width = $(window).innerWidth();
        canvas.height = $(window).innerHeight();
    });

    $(window).resize();

});
```

The full error I receive is:

`TypeError: this.canvasElement.getContext is not a function. (In 'this.canvasElement.getContext("2d")', 'this.canvasElement.getContext' is undefined)`

and it complains within the actual jQuery document which is very odd. I have this same exact setup on a another project and it works with no issue. A screenshot of where the error occurs is below:

[image]

What could possibly be going on here?

Comment: maybe u should post ur html code

Comment: Could you create a live example reproducing the error ? It complains in jQuery because the error is raised in a call to `$.Deferred`, but this call is probably done in oCanvas. After testing myself, I can repro this error when the element with the id `connect` is not an HTMLCanvasElement. So just check that your `#connect` is actually a `<canvas>` element.

Comment: @Kaiido How could I be so foolish! I can't believe I didn't check that! You fixed my issue! Thanks!